# DASH hexadecimal string comparison

Tags: dash, hex

I am attempting to compare two strings containing hexadecimal numbers in a dash test, one which has leading zeros and one which doesn't:

```
hex_string_1: 0x02a0000b
hex_string_2: 0x2a0000b
```

Trying `if [ ${hex_string_1} -eq ${hex_string_2} ] ; then ...` (or vice versa, the leading zeros don't seem to matter) gives me this error:

```
[: Illegal number: 0x02a0000b
```

Is there a simple way to compare these as numbers, rather than e.g. using `sed` to reformat the strings?

Since I'm using `dash` and not `bash`,`[[` isn't an option.

UPDATE: This worked (thanks ott!):

```
[ $(printf "%d" ${hex_string_1}) -eq $(printf "%d" ${hex_string_2}) ]
```

Comment: Why not just do a string comparison instead? Do you really need an arithmetic comparison if you're just testing equality?

Comment: `-eq` is only allowed for for what the shell accepts as an integer. Convert the values with `iv1=$(printf "%d\n" 0x...), then compare.

Comment: Please do not update your question with answer, that is information that doesn't belong there and not the way this site works. You should either ask ott to make her comment into an answer, or make it yourself into answer and then accept that. That way it is clear this issue is solved, because now it is not unless your not distracted by content like UPDATE and thanks typical for low quality posts

Answer (score 3):

POSIXly:

```
[ "$((hex_string_1))" -eq "$((hex_string_2))" ]
```

With older versions of `dash`, you needed:

```
[ "$(($hex_string_1))" -eq "$(($hex_string_2))" ]
```

POSIXly, About:

```
[ "$hex_string_1" -eq "$hex_string_2" ]
```

The [POSIX specification for the `[` aka `test` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) says operands have to be integers, without specifying which forms of integers (decimal, octal, hexadecimal...) are to be supported, but that's actually covered in point 6 at the [Utility Argument Syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_01) which states what the default would be when not specified:

> 6. Unless otherwise specified, whenever an operand or option-argument is, or contains, a numeric value:
>
> - The number is interpreted as a decimal integer.
> - Numerals in the range 0 to 2147483647 are syntactically recognized as numeric values.
> - When the utility description states that it accepts negative numbers as operands or option-arguments, numerals in the range -2147483647 to 2147483647 are syntactically recognized as numeric values.
> - Ranges greater than those listed here are allowed.

In practice, `[ 0x10 -eq 16 ]` only works with `posh` (`[ 0x1 -eq 0x01`] works in AT&T `ksh` (but only because they're treated as `0`, `[ 0x2 -eq 0x123 ]` would return true as well), and except for `posh` (where's that a [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=800365)), all `[` implementations return false on `[ 010 -eq 8 ]` (as in `010` is treated as decimal, not octal)).

In `ksh93`, while you can't do `[ 0x10 -eq 16 ]`, you can do `[ +0x10 -eq 16 ]` (also with `posh`). In both AT&T `ksh` and `pdksh` derivatives (including `posh`), you can also do `[ '16#10' -eq 16 ]`.

Comment: Posh's `test` does treat `0x10`, `020` and `16` as being pairwise `-eq`. ATT ksh, mksh, dash, bash, zsh, BusyBox and GNU test all treat `020` as `-eq` to `20`.

Answer (score 2):

You could always use `printf` to convert to decimal and compare that as @ott-- suggested:

```
[ $(printf "%d" "$hex_string_1") -eq $(printf "%d" "$hex_string_2") ] && echo y
```

Or

```
if [ $(printf "%d" "$hex_string_1") -eq $(printf "%d" "$hex_string_2") ]
then
    echo y
fi
```